# Can grep search for a line feed and a null character at the same time?

Tags: unix, grep

I would like to know this because UTF-16 files represent line feeds in hexadecimal as `0A 00` (little endian), and my patterns contain one or several line feeds, for example `\ntest\ntest_two\n`.

With the option `-P`, I tried multiple combinations of the options `-a` and `-U`, with the `-z` option, but it does not seem to work.
If I only looking for `00`, I can do it. If I only looking for `0A`, I can do it with the `-z` option.

But what about `0A 00` together?
NB:
I have to check a lot of files, not only one.

Comment: may be use perl instead? you can slurp entire file as string using `-0777` option..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> […] The string you listed contains both \x00 and \x0a, so regardless
>   of which of those two bytes you pick as the record terminator, it is
>   impossible to use grep to find that substring in your file. […]

Source:
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-grep/2018-09/msg00010.html